# How to I fill an object instance into an UpdateView form in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a CreateView and UpdateView, and upon success in the CreateView I'm trying to return the UpdateView with the object instance already filled in the form. The code below successfully creates the object instance (and redirects to the url with the uuid pattern in it as per the code), but the UpdateView form is empty. Why? How do I fix this?

views.py

```
class ProductCreate(CreateView):
    """Simple CreateView to create a Product."""
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductCreateForm
    template_name = 'productcreate.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        kwargs = {'uuid': self.object.uuid}
        return reverse_lazy('productupdate', kwargs=kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #some fields depend on request.user, so we can't set them in the Form.save() method
        product = form.save()
        product.fk_user = self.request.user
        product.save()
        return super(ProductCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class ProductUpdate(UpdateView):
    """Simple UpdateView to update a Product"""
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductCreateForm           #same form
    template_name = 'productcreate.html'     #same template

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        #get the uuid out of the url group and find the Product
        return Product.objects.filter(uuid=kwargs.get('uuid')).first()

    def get_success_url(self):
        kwargs = {'uuid': self.object.uuid}
        return reverse_lazy('productupdate', kwargs=kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^create-product/$', ProductCreate.as_view(), name="productcreate"),
url(r'^update-product/(?P<uuid>#giant_uuid_regex#)/$', ProductUpdate.as_view(), name="productupdate"),
```

productcreate.html extract:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

forms.py (I've left out the field cleaning code and a couple of additional fields not in the model):

```
class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form to support adding a new Product"""

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'field1',
            'etc...',
        )
```

Comment: Added the forms.py.

Comment: Have you debugged? Are you sure get_object() is returning an instance?

Comment: Michael, you were right; `kwargs.get('uuid')` is `None`. It needed to be `self.kwargs.get('uuid')`. If you paste that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Alasdair, thanks. In this particular UX case and for that POST data I prefer to fail silently and just show an empty form on the UpdateView.